# Input Shape error when using Keras Functional API with fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, keras, generator

I've built a model using Keras Functional API and it was working correct when calling `fit` on train set. Now I decided to change model to use my generator

```
def data_generator():
    while 1:
        for i in range(len(sequences1)):
            yield ([sequences1[i], sequences2[i]], trainLabels[i])
```

and here is a sample data from my dataset

```
sample = next(data_generator())
print(sample)
print(sample[0][0].shape)
# output:
# ([array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 10, 14, 16], dtype=int32), array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 19,  1,  4], dtype=int32)], 1)
# (34350,)
```

and here is my model summary (just the first two part)

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 34350)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 34350)        0
```

but when I'm trying to fit my model using this code

```
model.fit_generator(data_generator(), epochs=15, steps_per_epoch=64)
```

I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (34350,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the generator must generate the data *batch-by-batch*. In other words, `sample[0][0].shape` should be `(BATCH_SIZE, 34350)`, and the same applies to the second sequence and the labels.

Comment: what if I have (batch_size,34350,1) instead of  (batch_size,34350)? as I have one feature
please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64811632/keras-custom-data-generator-giving-dimension-errors-with-multi-input-and-multi-o