# Keras custom data generator giving dimension errors with multi input and multi output( functional api model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have written a generator function with Keras, before returning X,y from `__getitem__` I have double check the shapes of the X's and Y's and they are alright, but generator is giving dimension mismatch array and warnings.

(Colab Code to reproduce: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bSJm44MMDCWDU8IrG2GXKBvXNHCuY70G?usp=sharing)

My training and validation generators are pretty much same as

```
class ValidGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size=64):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.df = df
        self.indices = self.df.index.tolist()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return int(len(self.indices) // self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        index = self.index[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch = [self.indices[k] for k in index]
        
        X, y = self.__get_data(batch)
        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.index = np.arange(len(self.indices))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.index)

    def __get_data(self, batch):
        #some logic is written here
        #hat prepares 3 X features and 3 Y outputs 
        X = [input_array_1,input_array_2,input_array_3]
        y = [out_1,out_2,out_3]
        #print(len(X))
        
        return X, y
```

I am return tupple of X,y from which has 3 input features and 3 output features each, so shape of X is `(3,32,10,1)`

I am using functional api to build model(I have things like concatenation, multi input/output, which isnt possible with sequential)  with following structure

[image]

When I try to fit the model with generator with following code

```
train_datagen = TrainGenerator(df=train_df,  batch_size=32, num_classes=None, shuffle=True)
valid_datagen = ValidGenerator(df=train_df,  batch_size=32, num_classes=None, shuffle=True)
model.fit(train_datagen, epochs=2,verbose=1,callbacks=[checkpoint,es])
```

I get these warnings and errors, that dont go away

> Epoch 1/2
> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10) for input >Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32), but it was called >on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None).

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10) for input
> Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32), but it was
> called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None).
> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10) for
> input Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32), but it was
> called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None).
> ...
> ...
> **call**
> return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
> /home/eduardo/.virtualenvs/kgpu3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:975
> **call**
> input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
> /home/eduardo/.virtualenvs/kgpu3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:176
> assert_input_compatibility
> raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
>
> ```
> ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, None, None, 88]
> ```

I have rechecked whole code and it isnt possible to have input (None,None,None) like in warning or in error, my input dimension is `(3,32,10,1)`

**Update**

I have also tried to write a generator function with python and got exactly same error.

My generator function

```
def generate_arrays_from_file(batchsize,df):
    #print(bat)
    inputs = []
    targets = []
    batchcount = 0
    while True:
            
            df3 = df.loc[np.arange(batchcount*batchsize,(batchcount*batchsize)+batchsize)]
            #Some pre processing
            X = [input_array_1,input_array_2,input_array_3]
            y = [out_1,out_2,out_3]
            yield X,y 
            batchcount = batchcount +1
```

It seems like it is something wrong internally wit keras (may be due to the fact I am using functional API)

**Update 2**

I also tried to output tuple

```
       X = (input1_X,input2_X,input3_X)
       y = (output1_y,output2_y,output3_y)
```

and also named input/output, but it doesnt work

```
        X =  {"input_1": input1_X, "input_2": input2_X,"input_3": input3_X}
        y = {"output_1": output1_y, "output_2": output2_y,"output_3": output3_y}
```

**Note about problem formulation:**

Changing the individual X features to shape (32,10) instead of (32,10,1) might help to get rid of this error but that is not what I want, it changes my problem(I no longer have 10 time steps with one feature each)

Comment: Have you tried with run_eagerly=True in model.compile. That may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keras use 'None' for dynamic dimensions.

As you can see on the model.summary() chart - the model expecting shape(None, 10) for all of your inputs, which is two dimensional. With batch dimension - you should feed three dimensional data to the model.

But you are feeding four dimensional data.

I would guess that your model doesn't split your input list by three inputs. Try to change your inputs to tuple:

```
    X = (input_array_1,input_array_2,input_array_3)
```

Comment: Why the last dimension of your data is 1 ? The model expecting 10

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I just tried, but didnt help. I have exactly the same errors

Comment: 32 is my batch, 10 is time step and 1 is no of features

Comment: you have to change your model then - it is expecting 10 instead of 1 at the last dim

Comment: or just squeeze the last dim of your data

Comment: But I have same model running fine without data generator with same dimensions

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, None, None, 88]
```

TrainGenerator should be changed in the following way.
Current code:

```
input1_X = np.array(df3['input1_X'].to_list()).reshape(dlen,pad_len,1)
input2_X = np.array(df3['input2_X'].to_list()).reshape(dlen,pad_len,1)
input3_X = np.array(df3['input3_X'].to_list()).reshape(dlen,pad_len,1)
```

Should be changed to:

```
input1_X = np.array(df3['input1_X'].to_list()).reshape(dlen,pad_len)
input2_X = np.array(df3['input2_X'].to_list()).reshape(dlen,pad_len)
input3_X = np.array(df3['input3_X'].to_list()).reshape(dlen,pad_len)
```

The reason is that each of the 3 Inputs expects a 2-dimensional array, but the generator provides a 3-dimensional one. The expected shape is (batch_size, 10).

Comment: I have many-to-one architecture where I have 10 time steps and i predict next one. The change you suggested will take away all the benefit of sequential prediction as it will make data one time step with 10 featurs (dlen,10), which should be (dlen,10,1)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a custom generator that just had to pass a numpy array of size 10 as input and one single output.

To solve this problem i had to trasform the shape of the 2 vectors passed to the  neural network like this:

```
def slides_generator(integer_list):
    
    # stuff happens

    x = np_ts[np_index:np_index+10] # numpy array
    y = np_ts[np_index+10] # numpy array

    yield tf.convert_to_tensor(x)[np.newaxis, ...], tf.convert_to_tensor(y)[np.newaxis, ...]
    
doge_gen = slides_generator(integer_list) #next(doge_gen)
```

basically you need to pass the 2 arrays with shape (None,size),
so in my case were (None,10) and (None,1), and to achieve this i just passed 2 reshaped tensors.

you need the None dimension as the batch size.